# No audio output from PC

Tags: audio, desktop-computer

I am using a PC with Intel DG31PR motherboard in onboard Realtek audio.
I was not using the PC for around 5 years.
Yesterday I switched on the PC after cleaning the dust and everything.
All components work except the audio.
I have front panel audio and a back panel audio. Both are not working.
I am sure that my speakers are working.

I tried with Windows and Linux Operating systems. 
As far as OS is concerned, I can see the sound is playing by looking at various levels. But no sound is coming out.

Can anybody tell me whether it is a hardware problem, and if yes how can I resolve it?

PS: I cleaned the audio jacks and the audio chips.

Comment: I would guess a bad contact.

Comment: I would guess a 2nd audio device that is set to default that is not the device you expect, such as a HDMI from the graphics card or an SP-DIF.

Comment: Ok. but I don't have any extra cards

Comment: "bad contact" Could you please explain and ways to fix it??

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your speakers are set as the default device in Playback in the Windows Sound settings. If they are, check all volumes in the volume mixer and in the Speaker properties under Levels and check the settings under Advanced. Try running services.msc by searching it in the start menu, then right click "Windows Audio Service" and restart it.

Last resort would be replacing the motherboard.